# javafx file write; file inside is cleaned when energy lost my computer

Tags: java

I save my data using below method. Everything is normal. As soon as saving file if pc power off (energy lost) on ubuntu my file inside had been cleaned. If normal power off everything is normal. File saving finished but may be file connection is not finish. How can I solve this problem.

```
public static void saveMem(String mPath)
    {
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(mPath); 
            if(!Files.exists(path.getParent()))
                Files.createDirectory(path.getParent());           
            Files.deleteIfExists(path);
            Files.write(path, SendData); //SendData >>>this is byte array length 2000
            System.gc();
        }
        catch (IOException i) {

      }

    }
```

Comment: unrelated to fx

Comment: "Files.write" closes the file after all bytes are written. If power is lost before the file is flushed and closed there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: What behavior are you looking for? Do you want the original file to be untouched in case of failure? If so, you could try writing to a temporary sibling file then atomically moving the temporary file to the "real" file. Even then there could potentially be problems in the event of an abrupt power loss, but perhaps the window of opportunity would be smaller.

Comment: Also, never call `System.gc()` unless you know exactly what you're doing (and even then...). It doesn't work how you probably think it does.

Comment: (It's not dangerous, just generally pointless.)

Comment: @Dave True. I may have used overly strong language. Though one could argue it's conceptually dangerous as it indicates an attempt to manually manage memory in Java.

Comment: Before i didn't use System.gc() but i try find solution. Slaw "try writing to a temporary sibling file then atomically moving the temporary file to the "real" file" can be solution.

Comment: This isn’t really a Java specific problem.  Ever notice how Windows, and many videogames, say “Do not turn off your system while saving/updating”?

Comment: You are right This isn’t really a Java specific problem. but i try with very less data about 50 character and power off manually my file is had been cleaned. I think it must be faster for writing. When i wait some seconds and power off no problems. Slaw Thanks for suggestion.